# how to put text directly below a limit function?

Tags: latex

i already know

```
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)
```

but i don't know how to put the "along C_1" directly at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

`\text{}` allows text to be placed where the limiting variables usually go:

```
\lim_{(x,y) \text{ along } C_1} x^2+y^2
```

[image: Text to bottom right]

If you really want text to be directly underneath the `\lim`, you can use `\limits_{}`:

```
\lim\limits_{(x,y) \text{ along } C_1} x^2+y^2
```

[image: Text directly under]